# Update GPS map marker position Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to update the location of the marker placed on start up based off my location. However the first marker is placed when the app is open but it does not update. No physical changes are seen at all, "Timer called" is being written to the console so I know the timer is working.
My question: Why doesn't it update the location of my marker through the timer?
Also if there is a better way I'm open to suggestions.

Here is the code I have:

```
GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager _locationManager;
Location _currentLocation;
String _locationProvider;
TextView addresstxt;
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)// This works as it should on start up.
{
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
    CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 18);
    mMap.MoveCamera(camera);


    options.SetPosition(latlng);
    options.SetTitle("Vehicle");
    options.SetSnippet("Your vehicle is here.");
    options.Draggable(false);
    mMap.AddMarker(options);
}

private void CountDown()
{

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    timer.Enabled = true;


}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Timer called");
    mMap.Clear();
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
    CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 18);
    mMap.MoveCamera(camera);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .SetPosition(latlng)
        .SetTitle("Vehicle")
        .SetSnippet("Your vehicle is here.")
        .Draggable(false);

    mMap.AddMarker(options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that this may be because you can never know what thread a timer callback is run on and generally UI updates need to be done on the UI thread. Try running the code to update the marker on the UI Thread with RunOnUiThread(), e.g.:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => 
{
    mMap.Clear();
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
    CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 18);
    mMap.MoveCamera(camera);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .SetPosition(latlng)
        .SetTitle("Vehicle")
        .SetSnippet("Your vehicle is here.")
        .Draggable(false);

    mMap.AddMarker(options);
});
```